# Export csv with plain html to open it in excel

Tags: html, excel, csv, utf-8

I created an export into a csv file using base64:

```
<a download="export.csv" href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,BASE_64_STRING_HERE">Export file</a>
```

When i open the file in Notepad i get something like:

```
"test";"äää";"üüü"
"test2";"ddd";"eee"
```

-> ä,ü,ö are shown right.

When i open this file in excel i get `Ã¤` instead of `ä` and other things with ü and ö.

How can i set the charset of this file correctly?

**Importent:**
When i open the file in Notepad++ and change it to UTF-8 (instead of UTF-8 without BOM) all works fine.

Is there any way to export utf-8 files with `application/octet-stream`?

Thanks

Comment: you'd have to tell excel that the file's in utf-8. it's probably picking win-1252 or something. just having your mime header at the http/html level is pointless - that's information for the browser, and is destroyed/lost when the file gets saved to disk.

Comment: Can't i save the file with the information in it? When i change the file format in notepad++ and save it and then export in excel it works without trouble.